# Synchronize PyQt QGLWidget and QWidget (with FigureCanvas) when connected to PyQt signal

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, qthread, synchronize

I am using a PyQt to create a GUI. I have a solver thread that computes data to display:

**SolveODE** class (in a new thread):

```
class RepaintGLSignal(QtCore.QObject):
    signal_repaintGL = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class SolveODE(QObject):
    def __init__(self, MBD_system=[], running=False, stopped=False, finished=False, parent=None):
        super(SolveODE, self).__init__(parent)
        self.repaintGL_signal = RepaintGLSignal()

    def solve_ODE__(self, t_0, t_n, q0, TOL, Hmax, Hmin):
        while running == TRUE:
            #    calculate-integrate here
            ...
            #    update opengl widget every (N-th) step
            self.repaintGL_signal.signal_repaintGL.emit()
```

The simulation is controlled with **SimulationControlWidget** class and it has a signal connected to update OpenGL widget:

```
class SimulationControlWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MBD_system_=[], parent=None, flags=0):
        super(SimulationControlWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.OpenGLWidget = OpenGLWidget()
        self.graphWidget = GraphWidget()

        #    create solver thread
        self.solver = SolveODE()
        self._solver_thread = QThread()
        self._solver_thread.start()
        self.solver.moveToThread(self._solver_thread)

        #    signal from thread SolveODE is connected to OpenGLWidget to repaint - update OpenGL widget
        self.solver.solveODE.repaintGL_signal.signal_repaintGL.connect(self.OpenGLWidget.repaintGL)
        self.solver.solveODE.repaintGL_signal.signal_repaintGL.connect(self.graphWidget.plot_graph)
```

In a new window I added a graph using `matplotlib` with **GraphWidget** class :

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class GraphWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=0):
        super(GraphWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Graph of motion')
        self.fig = Figure((8.0, 4.0), dpi=100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.draw()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def plot_graph(self):
        x = np.random.rand(10, 1)    #at the moment I just plot some random data, just to check if it is working correctly
        y = np.random.rand(10, 1)
        self.axes.plot(x, y, 'ro')
        self.canvas.draw()
        print "graph updated"
```

The signal `self.repaintGL_signal` is emitted and connected to trigger two different actions (update OpenGL widgwet  and redraw matplotlib canvas). The problem is that when I start the simulation with **Start** button pushed the `OpenGL` widget is updating smoothly but the graph is delayed. To clearly represent my problem I added the `print` line after the graph is redrawn I get the following output:

```
Simulation is started
t = 0
graph updated
t = 1
graph updated
...
Simulation is finished
graph updated
graph updated
graph updated
graph updated
graph updated
graph updated
```

But the output should be like this

```
Simulation is started
t = 0
graph updated
t = 1
graph updated
t = 2
graph updated
t = 3
graph updated
t = 4
graph updated
...
Simulation is finished
```

I would like to ask you how can I solve this problem? The entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/avstenit/DyS/tree/master/src/V46).

Comment: You may want to have a look at MV Programming (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html), if your widgets can support it. And maybe multithreading (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html) if you want to remove time consuming processes from your widgets.

Comment: @Plouff If I understand correctly MV - Model View is used to display editable tree view or how do you suggest its implementation? I tried to put `self.canvas` in a new `QThread` but nothing changed.

Comment: The idea of MV is to separate data from its representation. Qt provides basic widget for that: combobox, list, table and tree. You can also subclass `QAbstractItemView` but it is a long process. Regarding multithreading, you can't put widget out of the main thread: it is forbidden. You can only put processes that will interact with your views thru signal/slot connection or shared variables.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that my feeling, is that you have a long process that is preventing your graph to be updated smoothly. That is why I think that if you separate the processing of your data from the representation of those data in two threads, it might improve the user experience.

Comment: @Plouff On the [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12580896/gui.png), there is a current GUI design (print screen) for better understanding. `QtOpenGL.QGLWidget` is set as central widget, solver is in new thread `QThread`, Tree View is under construction, Graph widget has `self.canvas` in new `QThread` but the problem is not solved. I think I will look in `queue` module...

Comment: @Plouff As you said I think that when the solver emits the signal to update the `QGLWidget` this is done quickly, but the update (or redraw) of `matplotlib` canvas takes more time, so the solver goes to next step, before the `matplotlib` canvas is redrawn from previous step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67627/discussion-between-avstenit-and-plouff).